# how to hide toolbar in news discussion app

Tags: sharepoint-online, hide-elements

[image]

How can I hide this part of the tool bar on my wiki page in SPO?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS code to hide the tool bar:

```
<style type="text/css">

.ms-comm-forumHeaderContainer
{  display:none;}

</style>
```

[image]